# Como imprimir imagens e texto (Cupom) em impressoras térmicas ELGIN I9 em C#?

Tags: c#, impressora

Recebi uma demanda para implementar um programa com a impressora da ELGIN, versão I9. Esse programa será similar aqueles que são usados em shops, mercados em que tem que imprimir aquele cupom com a Logo da empresa.

Eu já consigo imprimir textos, código de barra  e etc... Mas estou no impasse para imprimir a logo junto no cupom.

**Então, alguém teria ideia como eu posso modificar esse código para eu também conseguir imprimir a imagem no cupom?**

Até o momento meu código é esse:

```
public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
    }

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the printer queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "i9 RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, byte[] data)
    {
        bool retval = false;

        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(data.Length); // Allocate unmanaged memory
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, data.Length); // copy bytes into unmanaged memory
        retval = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, data.Length);//Send bytes to printer

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes); // Free the allocated unmanaged memory
        return retval;
    }
    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }

    //if you want a wrapper function for you strings :
    public static bool SendASCiiToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string data)
    {
        bool retval = false;

        //if  you are using UTF-8 and get wrong values in qrcode printing, you must use ASCII instead.
        //retval = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));


        retval = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));


        return retval;
    }
}
```

e

```
public class EscPos
{

//if you want to use decimal values in your methods.
public byte[] intTobyte(int[] data)
{

    byte[] byteData = data.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray(); // coonvert int array to byte
    return byteData;
}

//initialize printer
//ESC @
public void initializePrinter(String szPrinterName)
{

    int[] command = { 27, 64 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(command));
}


//print text

public bool printText(String szPrinterName, String data)
{
    //for more character sets: http://www.ascii-codes.com/

    //for another charsets: 
    //Encoding ascii = Encoding.GetEncoding("ascii");
    //Encoding windows = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

    //you must use this encoding  for  brazilian portuguese special characters: ^,~,ç,á...
    Encoding brazilian = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM860");
    byte[] byteData = brazilian.GetBytes(data);

    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, byteData);




    return true;
}

// Print Position Commands
//ESC a n
public bool SelectJustification(string szPrinterName, int justification_code)
{

    //0= default 
    //48 left
    //1,49 centering
    //2,50 right

    int[] align = { 27, 97, justification_code };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(align));

    return true;
}





//Character Control Commands

//use this mode to cancel another mode.
public bool normalModeText(string szPrinterName)
{
    int[] normal = { 27, 33, 0 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(normal));

    return true;
}

//Character font A (12 × 24) selected.
public bool charFontAText(String szPrinterName)
{

    int[] fontA = { 27, 33, 0 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(fontA));


    return true;
}

//Character font B (9 × 17) selected.
public bool charFontBText(String szPrinterName)
{
    int[] fontB = { 27, 33, 1 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(fontB));


    return true;

}

//Emphasized mode is turned on
public bool emphasizedModeText(string szPrinterName)
{
    int[] mode = { 27, 33, 8 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(mode));
    return true;
}

//Double-height selected.
public bool doubleHeightText(string szPrinterName)
{
    int[] height = { 27, 33, 16 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(height));

    return true;
}
//Double-width selected.
public bool DoubleWidthText(string szPrinterName)
{
    int[] width = { 27, 33, 32 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(width));
    return true;
}


//Underline mode is turned on
public bool UnderlineModeText(string szPrinterName)
{
    int[] underline = { 27, 33, 128 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(underline));
    return true;
}


//print and Line feed
public bool lineFeed(String szPrinterName, int numLines)
{
    // fucntion LF 
    int[] lf = { 10 };
    for (int i = 1; i <= numLines; i++)
    {
        RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(lf));
    }
    return true;
}

//Generate pulse in Real Time
public bool drawerKick(String szPrinterName)
{
    // function DLE DC4 fn m t （fn=1）


    int[] pulse = { 27, 112, 0, 100, 200 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(pulse));


    return true;
}

//execute test print
public bool testPrint(String szPrinterName)
{
    //function GS ( A pL pH n m

    int[] test = { 29, 40, 65, 2, 0, 0, 2 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(test));

    return true;
}


//Select an international character set
public bool charSet(String szPrinterName, int language)
{
    //function ESC R n
    //0-USA
    //12-Latin America
    //
    int[] char_set = { 27, 82, language };

    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(char_set));

    return true;


}


//select character code table
public bool codeTable(String szPrinterName, int language)
{
    //function Esc t n
    // 0 - PC437 (USA: Standard Europe)]
    // 40 [ISO8859-15 (Latin9)]
    // 3 [PC860 (Portuguese)]

    int[] code = { 27, 116, language };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(code));


    return true;
}

//Select cut mode and cut paper
public bool CutPaper(String szPrinterName)
{
    //hex 1D 56 m, m =0,1,48,49

    int[] cut = { 29, 86, 0 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(cut));

    return true;
}


//activate printer buzzer
public bool buzzer(String szPrinterName)
{



    //hex data = "1b 28 41 05 00 61 64 03 0a 0a";
    int[] buzzer = { 27, 40, 65, 5, 0, 97, 100, 3, 10, 10 };

    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(buzzer));
    // RawPrinterHelper.SendASCiiToPrinter(szPrinterName, data);
    return true;

}

//*************************** barcode  commands **********************************

//GS h n - sets bar the height of bar code to n dots.
public bool barcode_height(string szPrinterName, int range = 162) // default = 162
{

    //range 1 ≤ n ≤ 255
    int[] height = { 29, 104, range };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(height));
    return true;
}

// GS w n Set bar code width
public bool barcode_width(string szPrinterName, int range = 3)
{
    //range = 2 ≤ n ≤ 6
    int[] width = { 29, 119, range };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(width));
    return true;
}

//GS f n Select a font for the HRI characters when printing a bar code.
public bool barcodeHRI_chars(string szPrinterName, int font_code = 0)
{ //default 0 

    //[Range] n = 0, 1, 48, 49
    int[] hri = { 29, 102, font_code };


    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(hri));
    return true;
}


//GS H n Select print position of HRI characters
public bool barcodeHRIPostion(string szPrinterName, int position_code = 1)
{ //default = 0

    //[Range] 0 ≤ n ≤ 3, 48 ≤ n ≤ 51 

    int[] print_position = { 29, 72, position_code };

    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(print_position));
    return true;


}

//GS k Print barcode
//<Function A>
public bool printBarcode(string szPrinterName, string data, int type = 2)
{ //for this example 2 = JAN/EAN13
    int[] barcode = { 29, 107, type };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(barcode));

    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(szPrinterName, data);
    int[] nul = { 0 }; // null char at the end.
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(nul));
    return true;
}

//GS k Print Barcode
// <Function B>
public bool printBarcodeB(String szPrinterName, string data, int type = 73)
{ //for this example 73 = CODE128

    int size = (int)data.Length; //  the number of bytes of bar code data
    int[] barcode = { 29, 107, type, size };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(barcode));
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(szPrinterName, data);


    return true;
}

//*************************** barcode  commands **********************************



//function to print Qrcode
public bool printQrcode(String Strdata, String szPrinterName)
{





    int length = Strdata.Length + 3; //  string size  + 3
                                     //int length = Strdata.Length; 
    byte length_low_byte = 0, length_high_byte = 0;
    length_low_byte = (byte)(length & 0xff);//low byte used in function 180 
    length_high_byte = (byte)((length >> 8) & 0xff);//high byte in function 180 


    //if you don't want to use shift operator:
    //int length_low_byte = length % 256;
    //int length_high_byte = length / 256;


    initializePrinter(szPrinterName);

    //<Function ESC a n> Select justification  
    int[] escAn = { 27, 97, 0 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(escAn));



    //<Function GS L> Set left margin
    int[] fGsl = { 29, 76, 0, 0 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(fGsl));

    //<Function 165> GS ( k p L p H cn fn n (cn = 49,fn = 65)  QR Code: Select the model
    int[] f165 = { 29, 40, 107, 4, 0, 49, 65, 50, 0 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(f165));


    //<Function 167> GS ( k pL pH cn fn n (cn = 49, fn = 67) QR Code: Set the size of module
    int[] f167 = { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 67, 4 }; //  size of qrcode:  1-16
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(f167));



    //<Function 169> GS ( k pL pH cn fn n (cn = 49, fn = 69) QR Code: Select the error correction level
    int[] f169 = { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 69, 48 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(f169));


    //<Function 180> GS ( k pL pH cn fn m d1…dk (cn = 49, fn = 80) QR Code: Store the data in the symbol storage area
    //pL and pH are the low- and high-order bytes of a 16-bit integer value that specifies the length in bytes of the following data  

    int[] f180 = { 29, 40, 107, length_low_byte, length_high_byte, 49, 80, 48 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(f180));



    //send string/url to printer
    //RawPrinterHelper.SendASCiiToPrinter(szPrinterName, Strdata);
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(szPrinterName, Strdata);

    //<Function 181> GS ( k pL pH cn fn m (cn = 49, fn = 81) QR Code: Print the symbol data in the symbol storage area
    int[] f181 = { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 81, 48 };
    RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, intTobyte(f181));

    //


    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Ja tentou converter a imagem para binario e enviar para impressora para ver no que da?

Comment: Eu consegui fazer uns testes aqui, mas a imagem está imprimindo com uma qualidade não muito boa